# kohana view from what controller?

Tags: view, controller, kohana, verification

I have a view that could be called from any of 3 actions from one controller.
But, that view should be slightly different depending on what action caused it (it should display 3 icons or 2 or one depending on action called). Can I check in the view what action caused it so I can use if statement to check whether display each icon or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can pass `action` value directly to the view:

```
$this->template->action = Request::current()->action();
```

But View should not know anything about `Request` properties, its a Controller logic. I suggest you to pass special flags from your actions:

```
public function action_show1()
{
    // show only one icon
    $this->template->icons = array('first');
}

public function action_show2()
{
    // show another two icons
    $this->template->icons = array('second', 'third');
}

public function action_showall()
{
    // show all icons
    $this->template->icons = array('first', 'second', 'third');
}
```

Or set special flag (variable) for every icon.